# Problems with a string loop

Tags: java, while-loop

I want to build a loop where the console keeps asking me for a string until I write the word `"out"`. This is what I have till now, but it doesn't loop and I can't figure out why. Also I really want to use `while` or `do while` if possible.

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
String name = input.nextLine();

while (!name.equals("out")) {
    System.out.println(name);
    break;
}
```

Comment: If you want to read input in a loop, the line where you read input needs to be inside the loop.

Comment: Complementing @khelwood comment, it does not loop, because you're breaking right after the first iteration.

Comment: exactly, if i take out the break, works wonderfull. tyvm for the replys, have a good weekend

Answer (score 4):

You're not updating `name` inside the loop and remove the `break` otherwise you're jumping out of the loop in the first iteration (which is not what you want)

```
while (!name.equals("out")) {
    System.out.println(name);
    name = input.nextLine(); // I've added it here for you       
}
```

Comment: that gives me another option to write, but just one more, it doesn't loop

Comment: @Zmartinez77 what doesn't loop?

Comment: i got it to work, just needed to erased the break; ty for the reply